# Syntaxnet: Can I use my own POS tags?

Tags: syntaxnet

I have a large corpus and I would like to train my own Syntaxnet model with it. Training the POS tagger yields 0 % accuracy, and I believe it's because my own corpus uses different POS tags. The training generates a tagged corpus using tags like "NOUN", "DET", "ADV", and so on, while the original annotiation doesn't have tags like these. Instead, it has tags like "A", "N", "T", and so on.

How can I use my own corpus to train the POS tagger?

On what basis does the tagger assign those POS tags to the words in this case?

Comment: As a simple solution could you replace your tags with the expected ones if there is a one-to-one mapping?

Comment: I solved the problem a while ago. I am not sure how it happened, but I had to delete everything from the output folder and then it worked. For some reason, if the output folder already had a map and/or an output model in it, the training finished without an error, yet the output model for the POS-tagger worked totally incorrectly.